# Logback unwanted messages in TOMCAT

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, logging, logback

We're trying to use LogBack to log calls to services located on a TOMCAT. For this, we use an aspect which calls a web service to log messages. The services are exposed with CXF.

When we read the log file, there is a lot of unwanted informations about cxf like interceptors, endpoints, etc. while we want to log only what the log service receives from the aspect. Is it possible to do so with logback or do we have to use log4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in 3 ways.

1. The simplest way is to define logger level for package. Say suppose you have your aspect class and web service code in `com.myservices`. You can define configuration as below.

   ```
   <appender name="fileAppender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
       <file>c:/kplogs/logfile.log</file>
       <append>true</append>
       <encoder>
           <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
       </encoder>
   </appender>

   <logger name="com.myservices">
       <level value="trace" />
       <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
   </logger>
   ```
2. Alternatively you ca use Filters to accept or deny messages refer using filters [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html)
3. In worst case you can Appenders